# Thread synchronization with interlocked ops hangs in Visual Studio 2013 C++ native code

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm observing weird behavior with thread synchronization in C++ (64-bit Windows 8.1, Visual Studio 2013, native C++).

The object is to acquire read access to a data structure ("table") in memory. The counter `tableRIP` keeps track of how many threads have currently acquired this (there are 32 threads). It is also possible for a single thread to have write access to the table. When a thread has write access, no thread may gain read access. The bit `CacheLock_WriterWaiting` (=2) in `cacheLocks` is set when a thread has write access.

Here is the code:

```
volatile long cacheLocks; // bits below
enum CacheLockBit { CacheLock_Table,
                    CacheLock_LRUQ,
                    CacheLock_WriterWaiting,
                    CacheLock_Part
                  };
volatile short tableRIP; // # of readers now in process

Restart:
// Get read access to the table. If we need to write it, it will be changed to write access later.

InterlockedIncrement16(&tableRIP); // assume we will get read access
if(cacheLocks & (1<<CacheLock_WriterWaiting)) // non-zero if a writer is waiting or active
{
    InterlockedDecrement16(&tableRIP); // oops, a writer got in, so we're forbidden
    InterlockedIncrement64(&fc_Wait[0]); // counter for diagnostic purposes
    Wait(waitMs); // waitMs is a constant 1 (msec)
    goto Restart;
}
// Now we're a valid reader, and writer can't proceed till we've finished
```

The inexplicable behavior is, the program hangs in this loop. When I use the debugger and single-step through the loop (details below), it immediately exits. It is behaving AS IF variable `cacheLocks` were not volatile (but, as you can see from the assembly code below, it is).

At the time I am looking, there is only one thread active (this one). 31 others are waiting for this one to finish, and there is a UI thread also active, which does not access this data structure.

Since this is a release build, I am debugging using the assembly code and viewing memory directly. Here is the code again, but with the assembly code, as viewed in the debugger:

```
Restart:
// Get read access to the table. If we need to write it, it will be changed to write access later.

InterlockedIncrement16(&tableRIP); // assume we will get read access
00007FF789DF9970  lock inc    word ptr [rbx+2A4h] // (1) before 0, after 1 
if(cacheLocks & (1<<CacheLock_WriterWaiting)) // non-zero if a writer is waiting or active
00007FF789DF9978  mov         eax,dword ptr [rbx+2A0h]  // (5) eax -> 0
00007FF789DF997E  test        al,4  
00007FF789DF9980  je          $Restart+2Fh (7FF789DF999Fh)  
{
    InterlockedDecrement16(&tableRIP); // oops, a writer got in, so we're forbidden
00007FF789DF9982  lock dec    word ptr [rbx+2A4h]  
    InterlockedIncrement64(&fc_Wait[0]);
00007FF789DF998A  lock inc    qword ptr [rbx+1E0h]  
    Wait(waitMs);
00007FF789DF9992  mov         ecx,dword ptr [rbx+290h]  
00007FF789DF9998  call        Concurrency::wait (7FF789FB1000h) // (3) debugger breaks here  
    goto Restart; // (4)
00007FF789DF999D  jmp         FileCache::CacheInsureLoaded+0A6h (7FF789DF9966h)  
}
// Now we're a valid reader, and writer can't proceed till we've finished
```

When I "break" the program using the debugger, the thread is within system routine `Concurrency::wait`. I step out of those until I get to (4) in my code. Then I examine the memory at `rbx+2A4h` (i e, `tableRIP`), and it is 0. After single-stepping the `inc` it is 1, as expected. Examining the memory at `rbx+2A0h` (i e, `cacheLocks`), it is 0 at position (5) (i e, no writer active). Another single step and we jump to `$Restart+2Fh`, exiting the loop.

The program spun in the loop for hours until the debugger was used to single-step through the assembly code. You can see from the code above that C++ compiler has correctly treated the variables `tableRIP` and `cacheLocks` as volatile: it loads them from memory every time. I note that the two variables are adjacent in memory. Could there be some hardware feature I need to take into consideration? Processor is Intel Core i7-4771.

EDIT: In response to questions to my posting, here is more detailed code, showing all manipulations of `cacheLocks`. There is also usage of `cachePart[iPart]` locks, which is fine-grained locking of buffers; this is not related to locking of the table, and not all usage of the buffer locking is shown.

Parts of code unrelated to locking have been replace by `// PROCESS`.

```
// Data members of class FileCache:
volatile long cacheLocks; // bits below
enum CacheLockBit { CacheLock_Table,
                    CacheLock_LRUQ,
                    CacheLock_WriterWaiting,
                    CacheLock_Part
                  };
volatile short tableRIP; // # of readers now in process

// Code from class FileCache:
Restart:
    // Get read access to the table. If we need to write it, it will be changed to write access later.

    InterlockedIncrement16(&tableRIP); // assume we will get read access
    if(cacheLocks & (1<<CacheLock_WriterWaiting)) // non-zero if a writer is waiting or active
    {
        InterlockedDecrement16(&tableRIP); // oops, a writer got in, so we're forbidden
        InterlockedIncrement64(&fc_Wait[0]);
        Wait(waitMs);
        goto Restart;
    }
    // Now we're a valid reader, and writer can't proceed till we've finished


// PROCESS
    if(iPart!=bs_NotInCache && iPart!=bs_Writing) // i e, it's in cache and not in process of being written
    {
        if(cachePart[iPart].nLocks[lt_FileRead]==rl_FileReadLock)
        {
            // Another thread is setting a file read lock on this part, for unknown ix. Must wait, in case it's for this ix.
            InterlockedDecrement16(&tableRIP); // reader in no longer in progress
            InterlockedIncrement64(&fc_Wait[1]);
            Wait(waitMs);
            goto Restart;
        }

        // Lock this cache part
        while(InterlockedBitTestAndSet(&cachePart[iPart].partLocks, CacheLock_Part)) // returns 1 if bit (lock) was already set
        {
            InterlockedIncrement64(&fc_Wait[9]);
            Wait(waitMs);
        }

        while(cachePart[iPart].nLocks[lt_FileRead]!=0)
        {
            // Another thread is reading the desired block. Must wait till that is complete, then start over.
            InterlockedBitTestAndReset(&cachePart[iPart].partLocks, CacheLock_Part); // release the mutex
            InterlockedDecrement16(&tableRIP); // reader in no longer in progress
            InterlockedIncrement64(&fc_Wait[2]);
            Wait(waitMs);
            goto Restart;
        }

// PROCESS
        InterlockedDecrement16(&tableRIP); // reader in no longer in progress

        return iPart;
    }

    else if(partFromBlock[block]==bs_Writing)
    {
        // Another thread is writing this block--must wait till it's finished, then try again
        if(debugPartFromBlock)
            PartFromBlockCheck(workerThreadNum);
        InterlockedDecrement16(&tableRIP); // reader in no longer in progress
        InterlockedIncrement64(&fc_Wait[6]);
        Wait(waitMs);
        goto Restart;
    }

    // Desired block isn't in cache; must read it from file.
    // Now we need a write lock.
    InterlockedDecrement16(&tableRIP); // we're no longer a reader
    if(InterlockedBitTestAndSet(&cacheLocks, CacheLock_WriterWaiting)) // get 'writer active' status
    {
        InterlockedIncrement64(&fc_Wait[7]);
        Wait(waitMs);
        goto Restart;
    }

    // We have 'writer active' set, but we need to wait for all readers to finish
    while(tableRIP > 0)
    {
        InterlockedIncrement64(&fc_Wait[8]);
        Wait(waitMs);
    }

    // Now this thread is the only one accessing the table
    iPart=CacheFill(workerThreadNum, clt, ix, block, lType);
    if(iPart<0)
    {
        // CacheFill was unable to lock the part
        unsigned char locks=InterlockedBitTestAndReset(&cacheLocks, CacheLock_WriterWaiting); // no longer writer active
        InterlockedIncrement64(&fc_Wait[3]);
        Wait(waitMs);
        goto Restart;
    }

    // Convert the file read lock to the desired lock type. Current lock should be exactly 1 file read.
    long long locks=InterlockedCompareExchange64(&cachePart[iPart].allLocks,1LL<<(lType*16),LOCKPARTS(0,0,1,0));

    return iPart;
}

// Read a block which contains the desired bit into a cache part. Table is 'writer active'.
// If the cache has been modified, write it first.
// Returns the part #, and turns off 'writer active'.
int FileCache::CacheFill(const int workerThreadNum, const CacheLocType clt, const DBIndex ix, const unsigned long long block, const LockType lType)
{
    int retries=0;
Restart:
// PROCESS
    // Found an eligible part--try to lock it. To succeed, there must be no locks of any kind on the cache part
    long long locks=InterlockedCompareExchange64(&cachePart[iPartLRU].allLocks,LOCKPARTS(0,0,rl_FileReadLock,0),0);
    if(locks!=0)
    {
        if(retries>10)
            return -2; // unable to find an available buffer; wait till one becomes available
        InterlockedIncrement64(&fc_Wait[4]);
        Wait(waitMs);
        retries++;
        goto Restart; // try for another
    }

// PROCESS
    locks=InterlockedBitTestAndReset(&cacheLocks, CacheLock_WriterWaiting); // no longer writer active

// PROCESS
    // Now the old block (if any) is gone, so we can remove it from the table
    if(oldBase!=NoIndex)
    {
        // Lock table again. It was unlocked so other threads could run while we were writing.
        // However, another writer is not allowed to remove the 'oldBase' part.
        while(InterlockedBitTestAndSet(&cacheLocks, CacheLock_WriterWaiting)) // returns 1 if bit (lock) was already set
        {
            InterlockedIncrement64(&fc_Wait[5]);
            Wait(waitMs);
        }
        // No other threads can access the table, except readers in progress. We have to wait for those to finish.
        while(tableRIP > 0)
        {
            // No other threads can access the table, except readers in progress. We have to wait for those to finish.
            InterlockedIncrement64(&fc_Wait[10]);
            Wait(waitMs);
        }
        unsigned char locks=InterlockedBitTestAndReset(&cacheLocks, CacheLock_WriterWaiting); // no longer writer active
    }

// PROCESS
    return iPart;
}
```

Comment: So is the problem that it never exits the loop, or that it never loops? At any rate, the atomic ops seem to be not relevant, right?

Comment: Okay, upon re-reading, it seems that it never exists when run for real, but does exit when run in the debugger. At any rate, I would suggest that the problem is in the writing of cacheLocks. Note that you'll have to pay very close attention to memory consistency model. It's pretty strict for X86, but not completely sequential.

Comment: Guaranteed absence of deadlock in a program that uses 32 threads is exceedingly difficult to prove.  A starting point is to use a tested  reader-writer lock implementation.  Your question provides an [obvious candidate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504907.aspx).

Comment: It looks like cacheLocks is not being cleared by the writing thread(s).  Can you log the setting and clearing of the write lock?  Is there a possible race on the write lock?  Is it atomic?

Comment: kec: The pgm hangs (doesn't exit the loop) sometimes. It is always being run under the debugger.

Comment: Hans Passant: I have convinced myself that deadlock shouldn't occur in this loop. The 32 threads is not an issue, as at the time of observation they are all inactive except this one. This is a case where absolute maximum speed is require; hence not using a lock implementation.

Comment: Can you convince anyone else? Feel free to provide a proof.

Comment: @Woody20: At any rate, I don't believe that there is a correctness issue with the memory adjacency, but look up "word tearing" for more on that. I think the X86 architecture doesn't suffer from it in terms of correctness. (Performance is another matter.) All the atomic instructions are irrelevant, as far as I can see.

Comment: cachelocks is set and cleared later (in code I didn't show), using the atomic InterlockedBitTestAndSet(&cacheLocks, CacheLock_WriterWaiting) and InterlockedBitTestAndReset. But if it weren't being cleared, the memory location cacheLocks would be 4 when I examine it with the debugger, and in fact it was 0.

Comment: Alan Stokes: Deadlock either involves more than one thread, or would be deterministic within a thread. In this case no other threads are accessing the memory in question. That is not a proof, of course. What I need are suggestions why the posted code would not work.

Comment: if cacheLocks is 0, how does it loop???

Comment: kec: No, every atomic instruction is necessary when more than one thread is active. Otherwise, incrementing, say, tableRIP might give the wrong result.

Comment: Yes, but concurrent code will behave much differently in the debugger. You might be a victim of the fact that in the X86 memory model, a read can move ahead of a write if they are to different locations. Thus, some of the classic mutual exclusion algorithms don't work without memory barriers/fences.

Comment: Michael J: That's the question I am asking. It behaves as if there is a non-zero value cached by the hardware, OR that using the debugger to examine the location cacheLocks changes it.

Comment: @Woody20: I'm not saying that those atomic instructions aren't necessary for your application. I'm saying that from the code that we can see, they are irrelevant to the bug.

Comment: is it a numa machine?

Comment: Kec: Note that there is no concurrent code executing at the time I am single-stepping with the debugger. I am sure the hardware cannot reorder the reads in a way that would cause this loop to fail. A thread would have to have reset cacheLocks, but the read of cacheLocks was getting a stale value hours later.

Comment: Michael J: Yes, it's Intel i7-4771, which has a lot of cache memory.

Comment: @Woody20: Exactly. So just because it works in the debugger won't be that helpful to you.

Comment: kec: It fails when running in the debugger. It works if I "break" the program while it is running in the debugger and single-step it. If you're familiar with Visual Studio, this is a "release build", started with F5.

Comment: NUMA refers to the memory architecture, not the cpu.  how many cpus does it have?  If more than 4 it probably uses non-uniform memory architecture (numa) which introduces all sorts of potential gremlins.  :-(

Comment: Michael J: 1 CPU with 4 cores and 8 threads. All modern CPUs use NUMA.

Comment: @Woody20: I suggest that you post all of your code, i.e., the reader lock/unlock and the writer lock/unlock. Also, the way you've written it above cacheLocks could be a local variable. I'm assuming that it's not really, right?

Comment: I second the notion that posting all of the code will help here; I can imagine a (admittedly strange and somewhat far-fetched) scenario where there's a rogue writer thread active which completes quickly once it gets the chance and happens to get it right when you break into the debugger. Note that breaking into the debugger doesn't stop all threads at that very instant, but rather stops them one by one. Also, IIRC, PPL does some interesting tricks by context switching a single thread when one of the PPL synchronization primitives enter a wait state.

Comment: Its been a few years since I worked on big computers but the 8-cpu and bigger boxes used to cluster CPUs in groups of 4 cpus.  As well as the cache for each cpu, there was a shared cache for each cluster.  Also, the main memory was sometimes split into multiple busses, one per cluster.  If the memory you needed was not on your local bus, access times were slower.  To manage this, there was lots of fancy cache tricks that made concurrency rather messy.  From the sounds of things, this is not what you are seeing.

Comment: kec, arke: I will try to get all the lock-related code posted. cacheLocks is a member of the class in which the posted code resides, and so is not going out of scope. arke, you suggest the Visual Studio debugger stops threads one at a time. I cannot imagine how this could be. Once you click "break", the debugger gets control, thus stopping all threads from executing.

Comment: I have posted all the code which uses cacheLocks, as an edit at the end of the original post.

Comment: I can't see a problem, but the code is complex enough to make errors a high risk.  I hate all the gotos, but I doubt that is the problem (unless the optimizer doesn't handle gotos, which is unlikely).  Other than the possibility of a cache bug, the only other possibility I can think of is maybe a buffer overrun is clobbering cacheLocks.  Is there an array before cacheLocks in memory?  If so, for a test make it hugely long so an overrun can't happen.  If that fixes something, you can debug for the bad array access.  Beyond that: good luck.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

**Additional information:**

Referring to the initial loop, it looks as if what is happening is that `Wait(1 msec)` is never returning. What is supposed to happen is that after a brief wait, the thread checks `cacheLocks` again.

When the pgm is 'broken' with the debugger, then continued, the hung thread resumes, finds `cacheLocks` = 0, and exits the loop.

The Wait function is just

```
void Wait(const int msec)
{
    Concurrency::wait(msec);
    return;
}
```

All worker threads are running at priority "Lowest", except the main UI thread, which is at "Normal". I cannot find any information on how `Concurrency::wait(msec)` and the Windows thread scheduler work in detail.

Perhaps someone can explain why this happens?